# New to JS: Very basic else statement not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, so I'm trying to make a basic toggle function in JS for a list item. So far, I've gotten my if/else statement halfway working, but the problem I can't seem to figure out is why my else statement isn't working. The syntax looks good and I'm not seeing any one errors showing up other than the fact that undoing line-through isn't taking.

```
<li><input type="checkbox" onClick="check('box4')"><span id="box4">Mustard</span></li>

function check() {
    var el = document.getElementById('box4');
    if (el.checked = true) {
        el.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    } else {
        el.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IF Statement Always True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814334/if-statement-always-true)

Answer (score 1):

The `if` condition is wrong. Use `===`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to check if the `span` is checked, you want to check if the `input` is checked. You can pass the input to the function as a variable, then check if the variable is checked in your JS.

And you're missing an extra `=` in your comparison. `==` or `===` will compare the former to the latter in your comparison. A single `=` sets the former to the latter.

```js
function check(el) {
  var span = document.getElementById('box4');
  if (el.checked == true) {
    span.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  } else {
    span.style.textDecoration = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<li><input type="checkbox" onClick="check(this)"><span id="box4">Mustard</span></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `==` or `===` for comparison. The first one is an abstract comparison and the second one is a strict comparison which also check the type of the variables.

If you will evaluate a boolean variable, you can simple check with `if(el.checked)`.

Finally, you're evaluating the span value. You can change the id from the span to the input checkbox:

`<li><input type="checkbox" onClick="check()" id="box4"><span>Mustard</span></li>`

Answer (score 0):

The if/else is not working because you need to use `==` not `=`.

On the other hand the rest of the code will also not work because you are checking the `#box4` element which is a `span` so it does not have a `checked` property.

You should give the checkbox an id as well to find out if it checked

```js
function check() {
    var el = document.getElementById('box4'),
        span = document.getElementById('box4text');
    if (el.checked == true) {
        span.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    } else {
        span.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<li><input id="box4" type="checkbox" onClick="check('box4')"><span id="box4text">Mustard</span></li>
```

(*since the `checked` property is a boolean you do not really need to check if it is equal to true, you can use it directly `if (el.checked)`*)

---

Additionally, you could accomplish the same with just CSS

```css
:checked + #box4{
text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox"><span id="box4">Mustard</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you, this worked! and i see what i was doing wrong on top of that, muchos gracias!